# Azure Powershell - Can find package but not install it

Tags: azure, powershell, nuget, package, feed

I'm trying to install a package from a NuGet Package feed I created myself.

When I run

```
Find-Package -Source "packageSourceName" -Credential $cred
```

I am able to find the package as listed in the corresponding package source.

However when I run

```
Install-Package -Name "packageName" -Credential $cred
```

I receive an error saying:

```
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'packageName'. 
Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
```

Including the package source in the commands doesn't help.

Of course the package name is not really "packageName".

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: what is the output from Get-PackageSource?

Comment: `Get-PackageSource` lists all of my registered package sources. I can see the source that contains my package aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was now able to install the package using the nuget CLI in the console / PowerShell terminal:

After adding the feed as package source by using

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name "packageFeedName" -Source "https://packageFeedLink/nuget/v3/index.json"
```

I was able to install the package by using

```
nuget install packageName
```